# Best way to detect mobile and tablet devices and redirect them to another url?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, redirect, mobile, detection

I've been reading up on mobile detection and it seems with all the good there is also some bad,

I am wanting to know what is best way to detect mobile phones and tablets and then have the site redirect them to a page especially for mobile and tablet devices.

Can anyone direct me to a good js plugin or .htaccess solution?
and then maybe point out the good and bad in both to help me decide

Here is one htaccess code I found here on stackoverflow:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# Check if this is the noredirect query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)m=0(&|$)
# Set a cookie, and skip the next rule
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mredir:0:www.website.com]

# Check if this looks like a mobile device
# (You could add another [OR] to the second one and add in what you
#  had to check, but I believe most mobile devices should send at
#  least one of these headers)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "acs|alav|alca|amoi|audi|aste|avan|benq|bird|blac|blaz|brew|cell|cldc|cmd-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "dang|doco|eric|hipt|inno|ipaq|java|jigs|kddi|keji|leno|lg-c|lg-d|lg-g|lge-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  "maui|maxo|midp|mits|mmef|mobi|mot-|moto|mwbp|nec-|newt|noki|opwv" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "palm|pana|pant|pdxg|phil|play|pluc|port|prox|qtek|qwap|sage|sams|sany" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "sch-|sec-|send|seri|sgh-|shar|sie-|siem|smal|smar|sony|sph-|symb|t-mo" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "teli|tim-|tosh|tsm-|upg1|upsi|vk-v|voda|w3cs|wap-|wapa|wapi" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "wapp|wapr|webc|winw|winw|xda|xda-" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "up.browser|up.link|windowssce|iemobile|mini|mmp" [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "symbian|midp|wap|phone|pocket|mobile|pda|psp" [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !macintosh [NC]

# Check if we're not already on the mobile site
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.
# Can not read and write cookie in same request, must duplicate condition
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)m=0(&|$) 

# Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE}        !^.*mredir=0.*$ [NC]

# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.website.com [R,L]
```

from Shaun Russell

and here is a plugin I liked the look of because of this simple code:

```
 SA.redirection_mobile ({
        mobile_url : "mobile.whatever.com",
        tablet_host : "tablet.whatever.com",
    });
```

https://github.com/sebarmeli/JS-Redirection-Mobile-Site

So any pointers/best method you would recommend? 
Thank you in advance for any feedback or help.

Edit: I know bootstrap is the best way but not for what i'm currently doing with this site (webgl).

Comment: Don't do it. Just don't do it.

Comment: I recommend having a look at [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) for detecting the user agent

Comment: Well, the best way is making your site responsive (media-queries,...) and don't redirect them

Comment: @michael not exactly a good opinion when you have webgl running on it though.

Comment: @michael, the web is not all blogs.

Answer (score 1):

My best one is Apache Mobile Filter or AMF. It is an open-source project created by Idel Fuschini and distributed under the GNU General Public License (GPL) . See more http://www.apachemobilefilter.org/ 
But for more than one reason the best approche is to make a bootstrap responsive design that fit any screen without any redirections

Comment: In normal terms yes bootstrap is best but when working with webgl well different devices....it gets dirty.